# How to Mongoose send different value on find of specific field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a field which contain **url** to an image which is protected. It needs a secret to access file and the secret expire after a time. I want that when I do `Mode.find()` then the **url** value get replaced by anther **url** which contains the secret. So, that I don't have to manually every where I find from the model.

```js
const schema = new Schema({
  url:String
})

const Model = model('ModelName', Schema)
```

- Saved url in database

```json
url:"id_of_image.jpg"
```

- Expected url when find

```json
url:"/uploads/id_of_image.jpg?secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: What I understood is, you want your url key value to get replaced with secret url when you execute `Model.find()`. Hopefully, you are more concerned about the response an user gets. So better you can replace the url value after fetching it from database before sending it as a response. Can you please share your backend side code?

Comment: You got the point. What is solution of it.

Comment: I don't think... you can change the data output while executing `.find()`. You can either add a middleware function b/w your backend and database, and replace the url value in the middleware function, or else create a utility function and use it wherever you want to change the value. Please add your node.js code, I can't help much without that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can use [virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals). Something like:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  url:String
}, {
  // use these options to include virtual fields in response
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
});

schema.virtual('secretUrl').get(function() {
  return this.url + ' ' + yourSecret;
});
```

Or if you want to replace your `url` field with secret url, you can use [getters](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#getters).

Comment: Getters will work for me. One thing that can the getters be async?

Comment: I think no refer to this issue: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/517#issuecomment-2077096